# CSS overflow and white-space not working

Tags: html, css

### Current Situation

Using the following code I show a couple of divs floated to the left.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.inner-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.column {
  height: 500px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
  </div>

  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="column">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Current result:

[image]

### Problem

What I want is that the red boxes don't wrap within its container. I want both, a vertical and horizontal scroll bar if the space is not enough. For the vertical scrollbar it works. What am I missing?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brainchest/j6zh400v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix I found was to change the `.column` from being a `float: left` to `display: inline-block`. This treats each column as a "word" (like a word in text) and thus the `white-space: no-wrap;` applies. Otherwise, the `float: left` changes the way the element gets positioned.

Edited Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9bo4f5pv/

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` on the parent, then `flex: 0 0 150px` on the columns.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.inner-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
}
.column {
  height: 500px;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="column">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```